# Count intersections in set

Tags: python, set

I have data like this:

```
sample  event  caller
A1  5   version1
A1  5   version2
A1  5   version3
A1  5   version4
A2  1   version1
A2  1   version3
A2  2   version1
A2  3   version1
A3  5   version4
A3  6   version1
A3  6   version2
A3  6   version4
B4  1   version1
B4  1   version2
B4  1   version3
B4  1   version4
```

This shows `events` called by particular versions of a script (`caller`) for different `samples`.

For example, event `5` is called by `version1`, `version2`, `version3` and `version4` in sample `A1`:

```
A1  5   version1
A1  5   version2
A1  5   version3
A1  5   version4
```

Event `1` in sample `B4` is also called by `version1`, `version2`, `version3` and `version4`

```
B4  1   version1
B4  1   version2
B4  1   version3
B4  1   version4
```

This would constitute a set with two members - `sample:B4, event:1` and `sample:A1, event:5`

Whereas event `1` in sample `A2` is only called by versions 1 and 3:

```
A2  1   version1
A2  1   version3
```

I am trying to count the intersections between calls made per caller, so that I can see - and ultimately represent in a Venn diagram - e.g.:

- The number of calls supported only by `version1`
- The number of calls supported by `version1 and`version4`
- The number of calls supported by all versions
- ...

Here's what I have so far, I'm struggling with aggregating over all events:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from collections import defaultdict
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("in_file")

args = parser.parse_args()

calls = defaultdict(list)

# put a list of callers into dictionary keyed by sample and event:
with open(args.in_file) as f:
    for l in f:
        parts = l.rstrip().split('\t')
        (sample, event, caller) = parts[0:3]
        calls[(sample,event)].append(caller)

# For each call, extract the version support
for call in calls:
    s = set(calls[call])
    printset = ', '.join(s)
    print(printset, len(s))
```

---

```
('version4, version1, version2', 3)
('version1', 1)
('version4, version1, version2, version3', 4)
('version1', 1)
('version1, version3', 2)
('version4, version1, version2, version3', 4)
('version4', 1)
```

From this toy example, the output I'm trying to get would be:

```
Set_size    Callers
1    version4 + version1, version2
2    version1
2    version1 + version2 + version3 + version4
1    version1 + version3
1    version4
```

And I would represent this as follows:

[image]
**Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can achieve my desired output?**

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to count. Can you explain a bit more what the "Calls" number you want means? It might help if you could tweak your data so that the values are not all ones.

Comment: Why are `Calls` set to 1 in the example you want to get? Why wouldn't it be `2    version1 + version3` for the first line?

Comment: @Blckknght - That value would correspond to the number of members in the set. The question I'm trying to ask is "How much do my versions agree/disagree on called events?"

Comment: Your latest update to the question is much clearer. I think my answer is what you're looking for. I edited out the part at the start where I said I wasn't sure if it was what you're looking for, since based on the updated question I'm confident that it is indeed what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to count the number of times any event is called by the same set of callers within a sample. Your current code is a good start, but it only gets part way there. You need an additional data structure to count the occurrences of the same sets of callers. I suggest using `collections.Counter` to gather the matching sets together:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from collections import defaultdict, Counter      # new import here
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("in_file")

calls = defaultdict(list)

# put a list of callers into dictionary keyed by sample and event:
with open(args.in_file) as f:
    for l in f:
        parts = l.rstrip().split('\t')
        (sample, event, caller) = parts[0:3]
        calls[(sample,event)].append(caller)

counts = Counter(map(frozenset, calls.values()))  # aggregate the data

for callers, count in counts.items():
    print(count, " + ".join(callers), sep='\t')   # loop over and print the results
```

I'm assuming that you don't care about which events the callers intersect on. If you want to count intersections on different events separately, you'd need to include more data in values that get added to the `Counter`. For instance, you could count two-tuples, combining the event and the `frozenset` of callers:

```
counts = Counter((event, frozenset(callers)) for (sample, event), callers in calls.items())
```